# How to add query param to send request url using a pre request script postman?

Tags: javascript, api, testing, postman

I would like to be able to add a query param to the pre request script sendRequest url shown below, but havent been able to figure out how to do that.... I have tried to use different options to no avail. Thanks for the help!

```js
pm.sendRequest({
        url: pm.globals.get("base_url") + bankNum + "/loans/" + loan14,
        method: 'GET',
        header: {
        'Authorization': '********',
        },
    }, function (err, response) {
        console.log(response.json());
    });
```

Comment: Are `bankNum` and `loan14` also variables? If so, what types of variables?

Comment: Yes they are variables. They are just collection variables @ChristianBaumann

Answer (score 1):

I have tried the following and it is working fine

```
let guid  = pm.environment.get("guid")
let baseUrl = pm.environment.get("baseUrl")
pm.sendRequest({
      url:  `${baseUrl}/avc/api/xyz/setTrustModels?guid=${guid}&trusted=1`,
      method: 'POST',
      header: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Authorization': 'Basic Abcdefghijk=='
      },
      body: {
          mode: 'urlencoded',
          urlencoded: [
            {key: "grant_type", value: "password", disabled: false},
            {key: "username", value: pm.environment.get("OAUTH_USERNAME"), disabled: false},
            {key: "password", value: pm.environment.get("OAUTH_PASSWORD"), disabled: false}
        ]
      }
  }, function (err, res) {
        pm.globals.set("token", res.json().access_token);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pm.sendRequest(({
        url: "https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2",
        method: 'GET',
        header: {
        'Authorization': '********',
        },
    }), function (err, response) {
        console.log(response.json());
    });
```

you pass query as ?name=value

you can also generate the required request by  creating a normal request and then printing that request in console . TO print the request structure use:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(pm.request.toJSON(),null,2))
```

[image]

Now copy that :

```
pm.sendRequest({
  "url": {
    "protocol": "https",
    "path": [
      "api",
      "users"
    ],
    "host": [
      "reqres",
      "in"
    ],
    "query": [
      {
        "key": "page",
        "value": "2"
      }
    ],
    "variable": []
  },
  "header": [
    {
      "key": "Postman-Token",
      "value": "f3e48848-4001-4f1e-862c-b316c85dd3e7",
      "system": true
    },
    {
      "key": "Host",
      "value": "reqres.in",
      "system": true
    }
    
  ],
  "method": "GET",
  "body": {}
}
, function (err, response) {
        console.log(response.json());
    });
```